# How to compare emails in javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to make an edit profile page in which user can update its current email or pwd by inputting current email and password and then give new ones. I am also sending whole data of user(including username and password) when he sign in through viewdata.

```
    @{
    var user = (User)ViewData["User"];
}
                <div class="account-info mt-3">
                    <fieldset class="border border-dark p-3">
                        <legend class="float-none w-auto">Account Info</legend>
                        <div class="mb-3 simpleinfo">
                        <label for="email" class="form-label">Enter Your Current Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Username" id="prevemail"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 simpleinfo">
                        <label for="prevpwd" class="form-label">Enter Your Current Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="Pwd" id="prevpwd"/>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-4 checkcred">Update Credentials</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 simpleinfo">
                            <label for="email" class="form-label">Enter new Email</label>
                            <input asp-for="Username" disabled type="email" class="form-control" id="newemail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 simpleinfo">
                            <label for="newpwd" class="form-label">Enter New Password</label>
                            <input type="password" disabled class="form-control" asp-for="Password" id="newpwd">
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
```

Now i want to compare the email that user enters and the email that is present in the user object.
here's my code for this:

```
    <script>
$('.checkcred').click(function() {
    var prevemail = $('#prevemail').val();
    var prevpassword=$('#prevpwd').val();
    if(prevemail==@user.Username&&prevpassword==@user.Password)
    {
    alert("Validated");
    }
    else
    {
    alert("not validated");
    }
});
</script>
```

But it is giving me syntax error on Console: Invalid or unexpected token.
Please lemme know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Aside from the incomplete code, comparing the *plaintext* password seems like a really bad idea. To be able to do that means you're not hashing the password. Hash the user input and compare it to the hashed password you keep in the DB.

Comment: I am currently working on mostly front-end and basic functionality. will use hashing and Json web token later thanks anyway

Comment: **Always** check the *rendered* output (view-source).  Your script generates this `if (prevemail=test@email.com&&prevpassword==test password)` - you should be able to see that you're missing the quotes around `=='@user.Username'` and @user.Password

Comment: Thanks! just wondering how dumb i am.